# Find force F applied to two stacked blocks on verge of sliding

Tags: physics

> The force is just large enough to make it on the verge of sliding out from between the upper block and table. Determine the force F at this instant and common acceleration of each block [image]

$f_s$ max for the lower block and ground is $100N$ while between the two blocks is $15N$ So the total force required to pull it out is $115N$. But the answer given is $140N$.

What am I doing wrong?

*The appropriate physics tag has been used to indicate it’s a question for the math part of physics$*

Answer (score 1):

Apply the Newton's law to the upper and lower blocks, respectively,

$$
\mu_1 m_1 g = m_1a$$
$$
F-\mu_1m_1 g -\mu_2(m_1 +m_2)g= m_2a
$$

Solve for for the common acceleration $a=\mu_1g$ and the force,

$$
F=(\mu_1+\mu_2)(m_1 +m_2)g
$$

Plug in the givens, $\mu_1=0.3$, $\mu_2=0.4$, $m_1=5kg$, $m_2=15kg$ and $g=10m/s^2$ to obtain
$F=140N$.